# React collapse gets overflow hidden on changing the height of the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a React [collapse](https://github.com/nkbt/react-collapse) component that works fine when the `height` is set to `auto`, but if I change the height by showing the element that is initially hidden inside the collapse container, the `ReactCollapse` component gets `overflow: hidden` styling. And that causes the period picker field, inside the child component, not to be visible on clicking it. There was a similar issue [here](https://github.com/nkbt/react-collapse/issues/163) that seemed to be resolved with the version `4.0.3` which I have as well.
My component is a children component inside the `ExpandingPanel`.

```
<ExpandingPanel
  title={title}
  isInfoPanelOpen={isInfoPanelOpen}
  onClick={() => toggleInfoPanelCallback(faktaId, true)}
>
  {children}
</ExpandingPanel>
```

The children component that has one element that is being shown and hidden on click gets the overflow hidden when the element is visible:

```
<div class="ReactCollapse--collapse" style="height: 944px; overflow: hidden;">
```

How can I fix this, so that `overflow` is set to `visible` and not `hidden`, when the initial `height` of the `collapse` container changes?